# Npgsql C#. Как получить массив значений?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, .net-core

Есть такая база данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке получить все эти записи получается такое:

```
npgsqlConnection.Open();
string query = "select * from public.shoes;";

NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, npgsqlConnection);
var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, как мне получить все значения ?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Comment: Что такое "скалярный", знаете?